# Oracle APEX: popup menu

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have seen in [this application](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=20411:1:888811517916461) a popup windows with a form inside.

Can anyone help me build a popup windows like that, or if there is any tutorial where I can see how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some modal form plug-ins like [this one](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/clarifit-simple-modal_56.html) on [Apex-Plugin.com](http://www.apex-plugin.com/index.php).  I haven't used them myself so cannot vouch for them.

Alternatively, use your browser's "View Source" function on the Apex page you like and you will see all the function definitions and where they are called.  It appears to just be using the standard JQuery libraries that come with Apex 4.0

### Update 04/10/2011:

I have recently used [this modal page plug-in](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/skillbuilders-modal-page_138.html), and can recommend it.  There is plenty of instruction, including a half hour YouTube video showing how to use it.

Comment: but that is not the same as the example. I was shearching for something like the example

Comment: i found this plugin http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/popup-box_84.html but it only permit to add text to it but it is like the example