# How to create context menus which appear on right clicking in oracle apex report?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to display a context menu when a user right clicks on a report
and the user can perform an action on the rows selected. How to achieve this?

I can see there is already an action button on top of an interactive report. Can we customize that?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this. Though, what kind of an "action" would you want to do?

Comment: It would be business logic associated with rows selected. For example update salaries of the selected employees. The update can be done through a database procedure which gets called  when user clicks on the update salary option in the context menu.

Comment: Well, if nothing else helps, you could create a Select List item whose values would be those "actions". You'd then call the appropriate (stored) procedure either on page submit or via dynamic action.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992670/oracle-apex-popup-menu but as I'm not familiar with Apex I'll allow those with more experience to determine if it is, in fact, a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this. I see a few options:

1. You could hack together your own actions. You would add a Dynamic Event on `mousedown` on your report, then some Javascript to handle the action.
2. If it doesn't have to be a right click option, you can add a custom menu to a report. Here's one way of doing it. http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2015/07/13/apex-5-0-custom-menus/
3. Also, if using the Interactive Grid is an option, that menu can also be customized. See: http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/24/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a commercial Apex add-on product, I have used the FOEX add-ons with great success. However, it's not cheap and it would require changing your report to use their report-style (which we like).  Then you can add a context menu that's maintained via the Shared Components -> Lists.

https://www.foex.at/home/

I'm just a user, not a shill or employee...